# Android In-App Purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Presently I am developing one application in android.I want to implement in app purchase in my app when i click a button.

Please help me with simple example to implementing in app purchase for our app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe you should rewrite the question: right now it's missing the important part.

Comment: Here's an In App Purchase Tutorial: http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/simple-inapp-billing-payment-t52060.html also check out developer.android

Comment: Hey there you can look my library with example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26601734/how-to-implement-in-app-purchase-of-application-android/68227056#68227056

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am sorry to answer in this manner, but the documentation from Google is pretty good on the subject; http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html

The "Dungeons" example provides sample code that is pretty good.

In app billing is a bit complex, and uses some advanced Android techniques like IPC. I have been experimenting with this for the last two-three days, and I think you will have to do like me; close the office door and dig into the sample code & docs.

good luck! Please ask any specific question along the way. I am sure people will be more than willing to help.

Comment: I am using "DungeonsRedux" example for in app purchases, after purchase i am getting toast message thank you your item will appear shortly. i waited some time but i am unable to see those items in my purchased list. what will be the problem ? i have test account as primary account to my device.