# App Idle time in android appln

Tags: android, android-activity, idle-timer

I have an android app am displaying web view in my app but my problem is to find out the idle time of my app because after session expires i want show the login screen how can i do programatically in android.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Following link helpful for you. [Click][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700930/android-in-app-purchase

Answer (score 0):

if i'm given that problem, i would say have a timer running, with an incrementing integer every like 1 minute.  and if and interaction with the device simply resets it to zero.  there maybe a better solution to that though, that's just my logic.