# How to implement in-app purchase of application Android?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have created a android application. Subscription is free. However I have put ads inside application. Now I want provide option within app where people can buy ad-free version. And also provide option to restore purchase.

I went through Android docs didn't understand anything. Please provide a good tutorial.

Comment: https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3

Comment: http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/03/how-to-inegrate-in-app-purchase-billing.html

Comment: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_into_an_Android_Application_%E2%80%93_A_Tutorial

Comment: @rahul i dont know much about in app purchase i can provide option to buy my own app and how to handle restore purchase. I am providing two buttons one for first time buy and next for restore purchase of my app

Answer (score 3):

Hey I had worked on InApp Purchase recently and I've successfully integrated in my existing app and ready to make it live. Initially when i had started doing this I've downloaded google InApp Billing Example called "Trivial Drive" from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html#GetSample).

But it didn't help me much as it has lots of issues and bugs, So I've decided do it on my own from scratch using new v3 api which you can find [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html). This tutorial has clear explanation that would help you and also if you have time, see [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DgcJPIRpfSk) youtube video where google employee had explained clearly how to integrate it.

Also if you want quick example, I've a sample app which you can download from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y1en5phqz45hd7x/TestInAppPurchase.zip?dl=0).

The following video also explains how to integrate InApp Purchase. Please go through it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-h2ESH71hAI

Thank you

Comment: I want to provide in-app purchase of same app but ad free then i can upload same apk in in-app billing product section?

Comment: i didn't get your question, can you elaborate more ?

Comment: I have an app for free but i have ads in it. Now i have created screen in my app where user can buy ad-free version on click of button. So do i have two different apks or same apk with handling for checking if purchased.

Comment: Use the same apk, write the code in such a way that the app should check purchase every time when user opens the app. Then disable/enable ads based on the purchase response that you get from getPurchases() method. If user has purchased the item then don't show the ads, if not show it.

Comment: thanks ramesh... One more thing if user uninstalls app and we query will the product will be avaliable right.. i dont need to provide option to buy until and unless i consume it ?

Comment: yes, you are correct. You don't need to provide option to buy if user has already purchased.

Comment: okay for first i will have one button to buy and user clicks it this button gets disable until its consumed. And at start of app just check query purhcases and disable ad in-app billing apk as both apk will be same for main app and in-app billing..Right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63993/discussion-between-ramesh6233-and-vo12).

Comment: i did setup tester account with apk upload in beta testing mode but get this error:"The item you were attemptinh to purchase could not be found." I uploaded apk 3 hrs before

Comment: are you testing with signed apk? some times it would take 5 to 6 hours to appear in the app.

Comment: tested working fine now.. need to do some researching :)

Answer (score 0):

Refer this question on SO [Implementing In App purchases in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022945/implementing-in-app-purchases-in-android). Also for official documentation of The In-app Billing Version 3 API refer this link http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html

Answer (score 0):

This is how you create In app purchase inside your app.

1) In your developers console, go to your application and create a in app product(Name it as Ad-Free Access or what ever).(Note: to create a in app product you need to have a merchant account).

2) If you have a merchant account ready, create a InApp Product with the type of Subscription(One time or monthly or yearly) and price.

3) Once you have created the InApp product successfully, you can prompt the user to purchase an InApp product by quering a list of in app products in your app and ask user to purchase them.

Here is a [link](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/list-iab-products.html#DefineProducts) to query the InApp products:

4) Once a user purchase the product, based on the purchase status of the product, you can disable the ads in your app.

Comment: example will be helpful or tutorial and i dont have any product only one which is ad free version of my app

Comment: first, do you have a merchant account in play store?

Comment: that's the only way to create an InApp product.

Answer (score 0):

The Simple and very easy way to implement in-app through a library anjilab.
Just add the dependecy

```
implementation 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44'
```

Add Permission, implement methods and you done.
For any issues you can see here
[issues](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3)