# implementing In app purchase with updated library in android

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase

I'm having trouble implementing in-app purchases in my mobile app.
I want to implement in-app purchase in my application.can any one tell step by step procedure to implement in-app purchase in android application. I have googled and found many tutorials but they all are using old billing library version(1.2).I want to use latest version(2.2.0). Any sample project, tutorial...

Comment: Are you asking about billing client 2

Comment: @NatarajKR yes letest version(2.2.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These steps are based on my experience with version: 2.0.2. Since there are not any breaking changes in version: 2.2.0, the same applies to the maximum extent.

To start with BillingClient for in-app purchases:

1. A billing client has to be created using `BillingClient.Builder`.

```
billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(applicationContext)
                .enablePendingPurchases()
                .setListener(/* a PurchasesUpdatedListener object */)
                .build()
```

`enablePendingPurchase` method has to be called before `build`, as Google supports [cash payments](https://ww.9to5google.com/2019/05/09/google-play-store-cash/#aprd) in future, otherwise billingClient creation fails. A callback will be triggered after creation to `PurchaseUpdateListener.onPurchasesUpdated` method to handle pending purchases.

2. After creating a billingClient start billingClient connection.

```
billingClient.startConnection(/* a BillingClientStateListener object */)
```

`BillingClientStateListener` has two methods; one triggers when the connection is successfully established and the other triggers when connection is failure or disconnected. billingClient connection should always be maintained and retry mechanism should be handled in `onBillingServiceDisconnected` method.

3. After establishing a successful connection, make a call with billingClient's `querySkuDetailsAsync` method to fetch 'sku' details *asyncronously*.

```
billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(skuDetailsParams, /* lambda or SkuDetailsResponseListener object*/)
```

This method fetches us the In-app purchasable products created by us in play store to display it in the UI or do whatever we want with it.

4. (Optional) Make a call with billingClient's `queryPurchases` method to details for all items purchased within the app.

```
vaultBillingClient.queryPurchases(/* BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS or BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP */)
```

'SUBS' for subscription purchase details and 'INAPP' for one time in app purchases.

5. When user tries to purchase a in-app or subscription product check if the product is supported using billngClient's `isFeatureSupported(BillingClient.FeatureType./* SUBSCRIPTIONS or other */)` method and make a call to billingClient's `launchBillingFlow` method.

```
billingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, billingFlowParams)
```

billingFlowParams can be built using `BillingFlowParams` builder method by passing 'sku' details. System UI i.e., purchase bottomSheet will be shown. After the purchase is finished a call will be triggered to `PurchasesUpdatedListener.onPurchasesUpdated` method given for billingClient in the step 1.

6. After a successful purchase by the user, it has to be [acknowledged](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#acknowledge) immediately using either of `consumeAsync` or `acknowledgePurchase` methods of billingClient based on purchase type.

```
billingClient.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParam)
```

acknowledgePurchaseParams is built with `AcknowledgePurchaseParams` builder method by passing 'purchaseToken'. Acknowledgment should be done after [verifying purchase](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#Verify).

7. Once purchase is validated and acknowledged billingClient can be closed.

```
billingClient.endConnection()
```

**Note:-** *For all the steps mentioned above 'billingClient' connection should be intact. Hence retry mechanism on disconnection. It is better to start billing client connection as soon as app is opened to entitle the user with all his purchases. Also, there is no performance issue in always maintaining a connection with the billing client. However, it is up to developer how he grants user his purchases; either using his server or by any other means.*

For further reference, refer the documentation: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview

Comment: How to consume product after purchase

Comment: Use `ConsumeAsync` method of billingCient for one-time purchase products.

Comment: I want to allow user to purchase same product(coins) multiple times

Comment: yes, you can but acknowledge to the purchase use `consumeasync`

Comment: https://github.com/Marsad-Ch/testappp : can you please check whether I did everything right or not, and also please tell me where to add reward code (add coins to user account)

Comment: You can test your app by uploading to the internal testing track in playstore and specifying mail addresses of testers. Testers can purchase items without money. Try it. Also check the chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210583/discussion-between-marsad-maqsood-and-nataraj-kr).

Comment: Hey there, you dont need to read tutorial... all step done by my library https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26601734/how-to-implement-in-app-purchase-of-application-android/68227056#68227056