# GPay InAppSubscription SetSkuDetails

Tags: java, android

I am using Gpay In app Subscription and the older version of .setSku is not working anymore, here's my java code that gives an error when I am adding the String SKU key to the .setSkuDetails new method.

```
 BillingFlowParams flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                        .setSkuDetails(ITEM_SKU_ADREMOVAL)
                        .setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP)
                        .build();
 int responseCode = mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(SubscriptionsActivity.this, flowParams);
```

the error I get is

```
 incompatible types: String cannot be converted to SkuDetails
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `skuDetails` not `String`

```
for (SkuDetails skuDetails : skuDetailsList) {
     String sku = skuDetails.getSku();
     String price = skuDetails.getPrice();

     BillingFlowParams params = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                   .setSkuDetails(skuDetails)
                   .build();
}
```

For further reference, refer the documentation: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview